# SplitContainer is recognised as ActiveControl

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form I have two split containers and some panels and ActiveX controls and other Windows Forms controls like button, checkbox, etc. Now in the code I said

```
        Control activeControl = this.ActiveControl;
        MessageBox.Show(activeControl.Name);
```

but it is always returning splitcontainer1 as the activeCnotrl. How should I get the `ActiveControl`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that "this" is the form, when you call `this.ActiveControl`, it looks for the active control directly on the form (this). You will probably have to do somthing like:

```
this.splittercontainer1.ActiveControl
```

Comment: well I d Not want to hard code my controls names... plus I am writing this in a ProcessCmdKey and I dont know where I am..maybe I am on splitContainer2 or 3 or 4 !

Comment: Why did you downvote me? Your question was why the SplitContainer was being detected as the active control and how to detect the active control. You never specified that you had dynamic controls or that you are writing in ProcessCmdKey.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem, i solved it by checking if the control is a Splitcontainer and then Check the Active Control inside the splitcontainer.

```
if (ActiveControl.GetType() == typeof(SplitContainer))
{
    var containerControl = (SplitContainer)ActiveControl;
    if (containerControl.ActiveControl is MemoEdit)
    {
         //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted the negative one; It's simple but works.

Anyway I'd replace if (ActiveControl.GetType() == typeof(SplitContainer) with if (ActiveControl is SplitContainer)

Comment: In my case I had a split container inside a split container so be careful to do that recursively ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my generalized solution that should handle any nested container controls.

```
var control = this.ActiveControl;

while (control is ContainerControl container)
{
    control = container.ActiveControl;
}

var actualActive = control;
```